# Simple text Field Calculation In Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

the function is very simple:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, "DFDD", "aaa", "PYTHON")
```

and I want to calculate DHDD field with simple text "aaa", but I get error:

```
name 'aaa' is not defined. Any solutions?
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your expression (aaa) inside triple quotes:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, "DFDD", '"""aaa"""', "PYTHON")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can calculate a string to a text field:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, "DFDD", "\"aaa\"", "PYTHON")
```

One way to verify formatting is to setup the tool/parameters in ModelBuilder and then export the model to a python script.